# How to deal with computed properties in ReactiveForms Angular2 - Logic in Model or in the Component

Tags: angular

I'm not sure, how to correctly deal with computed properties in reactive forms.

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
   <input formControlName="name" />
   <input formControlName="surname" />
   <input readonly [value]="form.get('name').value() + ' ' + form.get('surname').value()" /> //fullname
</form>
```

Where should I best put the Logic to get the fullname here? I can put it in the Component or I can put it in my Model. I prefere to put it in my Model, but then I have to inform my Model about changes.

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
   <input formControlName="name" (ngModelChange)="model.name = $event"/>
   <input formControlName="surname" (ngModelChange)="model.name = $event"/>
   <input readonly [value]="model.fullName" />
</form>
```

Is there a way to sync the reactiveForms Values with a model? Is it a good practice to update the values in 2 places? I prefere to have my business logic inthe model but maintaining the data in 2 places feels strange.

Comment: In your first example, you missed the .vlaue() after getting the formControls.When you type in the fullname input, you want it to modify the name and surname also?

Comment: You're right. This is just an example, in reality the computed properties have more or less complex Logic. And no, I forgot to add readonly to the computed fields.

Comment: I would choose first option. Why make "unnecessary" model in this case? as a sidenote, it should be `value` and not `value()` :)

Comment: So both examples are working. You are asking for the best practice that's it?

Comment: Yeah in the end I'm just asking about the best practice, because I've seen no examples deaing with that topic.